# Apache won't start in wamp server version 2.4.4

Tags: apache

when I run command in cmd **`C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin\httpd`** 
as given solution in a question of stack overflow about Apache is not starting it is given the following error:

> C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin>httpd.exe: Syntax error on `line 539` of C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4/conf/httpd.conf: Could not open config directory `C:/wamp/vhosts`: The system cannot find the path specified.

But my `Apache Service` is not starting and I am unable to understand the problem as my `Wamp Server` is working from last 2 months and suddenly this problem occurs as error log of `Apache Service` is not showing any error.

Answer (score 0):

Your vhost dir points to C:/wamp/vhosts instead of C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\extra you should be able to chante that in your httpd.conf

Edit this in httpd.conf

> ## Virtual hosts
>
> Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

Then you should also check your vhosts config in httpd-vhosts.conf